# Extending a class that already implements an Interface

Tags: java, inheritance

If I had a class:

```
public class Foo implements Serializable{
...
}
```

and I have a class

```
public class Hoo extends Foo{
...
}
```

Does that mean that Hoo is also Serializable?

Thanks!

Comment: How about testing it? Try to serialize instance of Hoo, or maybe just check if you can use it via reference of `Serializable` type, or if it is `insteanceof Serializable`.

Comment: Why not find out? Try `Serializable test = new Hoo();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Expansion of comment by [@ajb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464386/ajb):

From [JLS 8.1.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.5)

> An interface type I is a superinterface of class type C if any of the
>   following is true:
>
> - I is a direct superinterface of C.
> - C has some direct superinterface J for which I is a superinterface, using the definition of "superinterface of an    interface" given in
>     §9.1.3.
> - I is a superinterface of the direct superclass of C.

The third bullet addresses your question.